# Update in MySql,with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble updating my sql table in laravel, because it changes the page but does not update in the database.
I need to have the form refresh the database after clicking Atualizar.

My Route

```
 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/admin/paginas/{id}', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
    Route::post('/admin/paginas/{id}', 'AdminController@update')->name('admin');
```

My Controller

```
                public function index($id)
            {
                $paginas = DB::select('select * from paginas');
                $conteudo = DB::select('select * from paginas where id = ?', [$id]);

                 return view("admin//paginas", compact('paginas','conteudo'));
            }

            public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            DB::table('paginas')
                    ->where('id', $id)
                    ->update(['conteudo' => $request->input('editor1')]);

            return redirect('home');

        }
```

My View

```
@foreach($paginas as $p)
    @endforeach
    <form  method="POST" action="/admin/paginas/{id}">
         {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Selecione a página</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="page" onChange="AbrirSecao(this.value)" data-placeholder='Nenhum valor selecionado...'>
            <option value="" selected>Selecione uma página...</option>
             @foreach($paginas as $paginas)
          <option value="{{$paginas->id}}">{{$paginas->titulo}}</option>
             @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
    @foreach($conteudo as $conteudo)
    @endforeach

     <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"><?=$conteudo->conteudo?></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block">ATUALIZAR</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check on your update function id value if get it empty thay you have add on your form action like
"/admin/paginas/{{$id}}

Comment: I removed the targeting for home, and verified that the button on the trigger sends to the id 5, is probably taking the wrong id in the form.
Are the routes correct?

Comment: Solved, I was getting $paginas instead of $conteudo. Thanks